# What is the precise meaning of "Surah"?

Tags: quran, arabic, terminology, surah

According to my research, the word "Surah" has some meanings, such as:

Enclosure, Altitude, the wall which is around the city.

- ([www.islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/tr22318))

But I was wondering what its precise meaning is?
Actually is there any tradition concerning its exact meaning?

*Note: I'm looking for the exact meaning of it which is used in the noble Qur'an*

Comment: Well the meaning in Arabic language could differ totally from the one even used in the Qur'an!

Comment: uh-huh, may be you are right. God bless you for saying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by checking the meaning from the Qur'an itself:

You will find this word ( the Arabic noun) Surah/Sura سُورة (plural suwar  سُوَر or surat  سُورات) in many Qur'an Verses (I'm not sure if i quote all of them):
In Surat at-Tawba ([9:64](http://legacy.quran.com/9/64)), ([9:86](http://legacy.quran.com/9/86)), ([9:124](http://legacy.quran.com/9/124)), ([9:127](http://legacy.quran.com/9/127))
In Surat Hud ([11:13](http://legacy.quran.com/11/13))
In Surat an-Nur ([24:1](http://legacy.quran.com/24/1))
And in Surat Mohammad ([47:20](http://legacy.quran.com/47/20))
In all of these Verses the words سُورة or سُوَر refer to a chapter from the Qur'an!

Now According to [almaany](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9/) (Please look at the Arabic/Arabic as Arabic English ends with the meaning described above) here are other meanings:

- Surah when speaking about a Building: a good, high, and "beautiful" one
- Surah when speaking of a wall: It's the deep root or base one start building the wall from -> technical term: foundation or footing!
- Surah also refers to a level, rate category or high standing pf something
- It could also be used for an indication, symbol or mark!

---

Notice that you might find in the Qur'an the word (noun) أساوِرَ this is a plural of إسوار which is often translated as bracelets!
You may also encounter the word (noun) سور with the plural  أَسْوَارٌ or  سِيرَانُ which is a wall or enclosure (see for example in Surat  and [al-Hadid](http://legacy.quran.com/57/13)).

---

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score 2):

I think the first meaning that you said ("Enclosure") is the best.  It means that *soorah* is like a  fence or wall to keep around some ayahs in Quran-Karim.

Comment: [In regards to salutations in posts.](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/107) Please avoid them.

Comment: Is this just a personal opinion, or is this actually based on facts and/or expertise?